# I want to loop through an array of objects in react.js and sort it on a condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

My `JSON` file looks like this

```
 {
    "PlanetIdentifier": "KOI-1843.03",
    "TypeFlag": 0,
    "PlanetaryMassJpt": 0.0014,
    "RadiusJpt": 0.054,
    "PeriodDays": 0.1768913,
    "SemiMajorAxisAU": 0.0048,
    "Eccentricity": "",
    "PeriastronDeg": "",
    "LongitudeDeg": "",
    "DiscoveryYear": 2012,
    "
  },
  {
    "PlanetIdentifier": "KOI-1843.01",
    "TypeFlag": 0,
    "PlanetaryMassJpt": "",
    "RadiusJpt": 0.114,
    "PeriodDays": 4.194525,
    "SemiMajorAxisAU": 0.039,
    "Eccentricity": "",
    "PeriastronDeg": "",
    "LongitudeDeg": "",
    "DiscoveryYear": "",
  }
```

Now my objective is to sort the object by `year` and then sort them again using the `RaduisJpt`.

```
if(RaduisJpt > 2) then it is large planet
if(RaDuisJpt <1) then it is a small planet
else it is a medium
```

then I have to show how many small, medium and large planets were discovered each year.

Comment: So do you know about Array methods like .sort() and .filter()? What's the issue here exactly? Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: The JSON is invalid?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

```js
const arr = [{
    "PlanetIdentifier": "KOI-1843.03",
    "TypeFlag": 0,
    "PlanetaryMassJpt": 0.0014,
    "RadiusJpt": 0.054,
    "PeriodDays": 0.1768913,
    "SemiMajorAxisAU": 0.0048,
    "Eccentricity": "",
    "PeriastronDeg": "",
    "LongitudeDeg": "",
    "DiscoveryYear": 2012,
  },
  {
    "PlanetIdentifier": "KOI-1843.01",
    "TypeFlag": 0,
    "PlanetaryMassJpt": "",
    "RadiusJpt": 0.114,
    "PeriodDays": 4.194525,
    "SemiMajorAxisAU": 0.039,
    "Eccentricity": "",
    "PeriastronDeg": "",
    "LongitudeDeg": "",
    "DiscoveryYear": 2010,
  },
    {
    "PlanetIdentifier": "KOI-1843.01",
    "TypeFlag": 0,
    "PlanetaryMassJpt": "",
    "RadiusJpt": 0.5,
    "PeriodDays": 4.194525,
    "SemiMajorAxisAU": 0.039,
    "Eccentricity": "",
    "PeriastronDeg": "",
    "LongitudeDeg": "",
    "DiscoveryYear": 2010,
  }
]
const sorted = arr.sort((a, b) => {
  let sum = a.DiscoveryYear - b.DiscoveryYear;
  return sum == 0 ? a.RadiusJpt - b.RadiusJpt : sum
})
console.log(sorted);
```